# "Эффект лебедя, рака и щуки". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

**В этом наблюдается эффект лебедя, рака и щуки.**
Нужно ли брать в кавычки слова «эффект лебедя, рака и щуки»?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, да. Выражение не стало общепринятым, хотя и понятно без комментариев. Так что кавычки уместны.

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки нужны, но  только после слова эффект, а не перед ним.